# In a tabbed view navigator application in flex mobile 4.5 how can i have a home tab which is not part of the main tabbed application?

Tags: android, apache-flex, tabs, flash-builder, ria

I am new to flex and i am building an application for a mobile device.

I have a tabbed view navigtator application which has tabs at the bottom.

On top i have an action bar with back and some other buttons not set up yet.

i created a home tab as i want to have a home page for the first view after the splash screen then with the guide which says select a specfic tab below, the problem is i don't want to have the tab for home at the bottom.

Is there a way to keep the homepage as a first view but not have it as part of the tabs at the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

In simple words:

1. Add IndexChangeEvent listener to your TabbedViewNavigator instance [ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/IndexChangeEvent.html ]
2. When index is changed or is changing check for tabbedViewNavigatorInstance.navigators[newIndex]  firstView equal Home.
3. If is Home hide Home tab else show Home tab, for this task check this post [ [Hiding a tab in a Spark TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129909/hiding-a-tab-in-a-spark-tabbar/11518142#11518142) ]

The implementation itself can be done in multiple ways depending on your current flow.

Here an quick example that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  applicationDPI="160" applicationComplete="onAppComplete(event)">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.DataGroup;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            import views.HomeView;

            private function onAppComplete(e : Event) : void {
                this.tabbedNavigator.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE, onIndexChange);

                showHomeTab(false);
            }

            private function onIndexChange(e : IndexChangeEvent) : void {
                var vn : ViewNavigator = this.navigators[e.newIndex] as ViewNavigator;

                if(vn.firstView === HomeView){
                    showHomeTab(false);
                } else {
                    showHomeTab(true);
                }
            }

            private function showHomeTab(state : Boolean) : void {
                var dg : DataGroup = this.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.dataGroup;

                ///if HomeView is at index 0
                dg.getElementAt(0).visible = state;
                dg.getElementAt(0).includeInLayout = state;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ViewNavigator label="Home" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.HomeView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Other" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.OtherView"/>

</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Comment: Great, Thank you very much, i'll research that now :)

Comment: Check my example, hope will answer your question. Cheers.

Comment: Works great but one question when hiding all tabs. The background is white, how can i change the background to black (because all other content has a black background)